# good OO design pattern for external service calls

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am calling an external services in three steps: Compose the request, send it and receive the result, extract the result.

Now there are several external services that I will be using, building on different application stacks (SOAP and REST for instance. How would a good OO-design for this situation look like?

My specific concerns are: I could have interfaces for RequestBuilders and ResponseParsers, and a ServiceCaller that would delegate the obvious steps to implementations of the interfaces. But that means one could have a ServiceCaller that builds requests for service A, and expects responses in service' B format.

Whats a good OO pattern for that in general?

Answer (score 3):

You can have a look at the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). The `Create` method of the factory accepts the type of the object required (`Request` of `ServiceA`) and returns an `IRequest` interface. All request implementation are required to implement `IRequest`. Once this layer has been built, you can create the service layer containing the builders for the appropriate `Request` and `Response` type.

Comment: Well said. It might also be worth considering the use of the [Abstract Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) since the op is attempting to create families of related classes depending on the context.